# Label color, or bar color, by row for Google Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I am using the Google Timeline Chart API, documented here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

Here is an example of what I have:
[image]

What I want to do is use two colors, some rows will be color A and some rows will be color B, depending on a simple boolean.

However, I don't see a way to do this given the configuration options for this API.

To be specific if a file exited with code > 0, I want to color the row yellow, if it exited with code 0, I want the row to be green. I don't care if it's the bar color or the label color, just something.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't expect this to work, but it did:

[image]

To achieve this, you use the API like so:

```
    var options = {
      colors: colors,
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

where colors is a one-dimensional array of string, that represents the color to be used for each row.